# Chrome extension: How to manipulate inner Gmail DOM with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

Whilst it is no problem to manipulate the inner Gmail content with a css content script, I fail to do so with jQuery and a custom js content script.

I want to use jQuery to manipulate the inner Gmail DOM.

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [ {
        "matches":      ["*://*.mail.google.com/*"],
        "js":           ["jquery.js", "default.js"]
    } ],
```

**default.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.gK").css("color", "red");
});
```

However, the respective `div.gK` element does not reflect the css changes:

[image]

Any ideas why this does not work?

Answer (score 4):

The DOMReady event fires long before your target element is created. When you go to mail.google.com you'll notice the loading bar - just before that appears your event is fired.

I'm not sure if GMail has any custom events that are more reliable, otherwise I'd suggest using

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery("div.gK").css("color", "red");
});
```

If you feel like dissecting the events in more detail I suggest reading up on and using the Chrome Developer Tools, with a focus on the [Timeline tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline?hl=fr#events_mode).

Comment: Thanks but I cannot get this working. The element remains unchanged. I also applied other functions on the element such as `hide()` but they neither work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your extension is not throwing an error by looking at the Javascript Console.
The problem might be that it's not executing because it's throwing an error.
CHeers!